# How to show the tick mark after clicking the popup button in Jquery?

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, modal-popup, checkbox, terms-and-conditions

In checkout, we have enabled the "Terms and conditions" pop up and my requirement is to show the tick mark after closing the pop-up but right now it is happening only when we click the checkbox.
Please give me suggestions to make this work.

Code for Terms and condition:

```
<div class="checkout-agreement">
    <input type="checkbox" class="required-entry">
    <label class="label">
        <button type="button" class="action action-show">
            <span>I agree the Terms Conditions</span>
        </button>
    </label>
</div>
```

Code for Footer:

```
    <button class="action-close" data-role="closeBtn" type="button">
        <span>Close</span>
    </button>
</header>
<div class="modal-content">
    <div id="checkout-agreements-modal">
            <div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="modal-footer">

    <button class="action secondary action-hide-popup" type="button" "><span>Close</span></button>
        
    </footer>
    
</div>
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modal has events for which you can bind a listener:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html#modal_events

Inside a function body add your code for selecting checkbox.